# Prime numbers, and their digital roots.

Tags: prime-numbers

**Edit**

It is clear that this conjecture is false, in many, many circumstances, and I am grateful to the whole Math Stack Exchange community for helping me to see this.

Thank you!

---

Let $p \in \mathbb{P},$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of prime numbers, and $S(x)$ be the sum of the digits of $x.$

Also, $S_{n}(x)$ is a function such that:

$S_{2}(x) = S(S(x)),$ and $S_{3}(x) = S(S(S(x))),$ et cetera.

---

**Conjecture**

If $S(p) > (10^{l} - 1), l \in \mathbb{Z},$ where $l$ is the smallest solution to $S_{l}(x) \leq 9.$ I believe that $\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{l}{S_{i}(x)}\right) \in \mathbb{P}.$

---

I have tried it for a few prime numbers, which means that, of course, it may not be true for all prime numbers that satisfy this conjecture, and I am not quite sure if 'conjecture' is the right term for such a statement, but I would like to know if one would be able to prove that this is, indeed, the case, or, whether it is nonsense.

Thank you.

Comment: The question would be much easier to understand if you trash the $m$, $f$, and $d$ functions and just write "Let $S(x)$ be the sum of the digits in $x$".

Comment: @HenningMakholm $m(x), f(n, x),$ and $d(n, x)$ are all functions that are required in order to calculate the $(n + 1)$th digit of $x$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have done this, now.

Comment: What is $x$ in your formula at the bottom???

Comment: @barakmanos I have replaced it with $p,$ as it was my intention to do so in the beginning.

Comment: How would you define $S_0$? Is it just the identity map?

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun $S_{0}$ would not exist, as far as I know. It would not make sense for it to exist.

Comment: @Taylor Then why does the summation start from $i = 0$? :p (That's what I was hinting at in my first comment)

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun I have corrected this error. I am sorry about making so many errors with this.

Comment: You've edited your question and you dare to down-vote my answer??? Shame on you!!! And by the way, even for $n=1$, it fails as soon as $p$ reaches $89$. Do you want to set the limit on $n=2$ perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

Your conjecture is false in several (probably infinitely many) cases:

```
p = 13 , n = 0 , t = 4
p = 17 , n = 0 , t = 8
p = 31 , n = 0 , t = 4
p = 53 , n = 0 , t = 8
p = 89 , n = 1 , t = 25
```

Here is a short Python script to illustrate this:

```
primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]

def S(x):
    return sum(int(c) for c in str(x))

for p in primes:
    x = S(p)
    n = len(str(x))-1
    t = x
    for i in range(0,n):
        x = S(x)
        t += x
    if t not in primes:
        print 'p =', p, ', n =', n, ', t =', t
```

Answer (score 3):

Your conjecture is false whenever $n=8, 17, 26,\ldots$.

By a well-known property of digital sums, the numbers $x$, $S(x)$, $S(S(x))$ and so forth are all equivalent modulo 9. Adding 9 such numbers will always yield something that is divisible by $9$.

Comment: @Taylor: Whenever $n$ is one less than a multiple of $9$. In fact every $n$ that is one less than a multiple of $3$ is excluded by the same reasoning. Given this, I don't see any particular reason why it should be true for other $n$s either.

Comment: $29$ is prime, and the sum of its digits is $11.$ The sum of the digits of $11$ is $2.$ $11 + 2 = 13,$ and $13 \in \mathbb{P}.$

Comment: $37$ is prime, and the sum of its digits is $10.$ The sum of the digits of $10$ is $1.$ $10 + 1 = 11,$ and $11 \in \mathbb{P}.$

Comment: $59$ is prime, and the sum of its digits is $14.$ The sum of the digits of $14$ is $5.$ $14 + 5 = 19,$ and $19 \in \mathbb{P}.$

Comment: @Taylor: To make your conjecture even half-way plausible, you will have to test it for all primes up to at least a few thousand. And preferably a few million. My personal feeling is that your conjecture is probably false, so you have to provide a lot of evidence to persuade me.

Comment: Thank you, Henning, for suggesting this, and, because of this, and the post by @barakmanos, I am happy to conclude that my conjecture was, unfortunately, false in many cases.

I am grateful, as always, to the Math Stack Exchange community for helping me. Thank you, all!